# Generate a marksheet with some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a mark-sheet for my PHP project where I have used JS to determine whether a student is 'pass' or 'fail'.

It checks the sum of 'pass' marks and the obtained marks. If a student gets `0` in one subject but the total is more than the required pass marks then it shows `PASS` in the result field which I don't want. I want JS to check if it's `0` in any subject and show `fail`.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm very new to JS. Please guide me.

```js
$(function() {
  var TotalValue = 0;
  $("tr #data").each(function(index, value) {
    currentRow = parseFloat($(this).text());
    TotalValue += currentRow
  });

  document.getElementById('fulltotal').innerHTML = TotalValue;
  var TotalValue1 = 0;
  
  $("tr #data1").each(function(index, value) {
    currentRow = parseFloat($(this).text());
    TotalValue1 += currentRow
  });

  document.getElementById('passtotal').innerHTML = TotalValue1;
  var TotalValue2 = 0;
  $("tr #data2").each(function(index, value) {
    currentRow = parseFloat($(this).text());
    TotalValue2 += currentRow
  });

  document.getElementById('obtotal').innerHTML = TotalValue2;
});

var ptotal = $("#passtotal").val();
var ototal = $("#obtotal").val();
if (ptotal > ototal) {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "FAIL";
} else {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "PASS";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Subject / Course Title</th>
        <th>Maximum Marks</th>
        <th>Pass Marks</th>
        <th>Marks Awarded</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="body-data">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>maths<td>
        <td id="data">100</td>
        <td id="data1">33</td>
        <td id="data2">54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>english<td>
        <td id="data">100</td>
        <td id="data1">33</td>
        <td id="data2">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>science<td>
        <td id="data">100</td>
        <td id="data1">33</td>
        <td id="data2">74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>social science<td>
        <td id="data">100</td>
        <td id="data1">33</td>
        <td id="data2">0</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="total-data">
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">TOTAL </td>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="fulltotal"></td>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="passtotal"></td>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="obtotal"></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Firstly, the PHP loop you're using to create the table is excluding the last `</tr>` from each row. Secondly, you're using `id` attributes in the looped content which will mean they are not unique which is invalid. Change all the `id` in the loop to use classes instead. Finally, given that the PHP isn't relevant to the issue, can you please edit the question to include the actual HTML output so we can create a working example from the actual data in your page.

Comment: You cannot repeat ID attributes in the loop as you are here...

Comment: i have edited the question as u asked @RoryMcCrossan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, consolidated a bit and normalized to all be jQuery. You seem to be familiar with most of this, but instead of parseFloat, I used the shorthand `+` which converts the string into a number (float or integer). Also code like this `+$(this).find('td').eq(4).text()` means *find the td with index 3 under me, get its text value and convert into a number*. Additionally, in your `pass/fail` if statement at the end, you were comparing strings, not numbers, so I updated that as well.

```js
$(function() {
  let maxMarks = 0, passMarks = 0, marksAwarded = 0, hasFail = false;
  $("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
      let val = +$(this).text().trim();
      if (index === 2) maxMarks += val;
      else if (index === 3) passMarks += val;
      else if (index === 4) marksAwarded += val;
    });
    if (+$(this).find('td').eq(4).text() < +$(this).find('td').eq(3).text()) hasFail = true;
  });
  $('#fulltotal').html(maxMarks);
  $('#passtotal').html(passMarks);
  $('#obtotal').html(marksAwarded);
  if (marksAwarded < passMarks || hasFail) {
    $('#results').html("FAIL");
  } else {
    $('#results').html("PASS");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Subject / Course Title</th>
      <th>Maximum Marks</th>
      <th>Pass Marks</th>
      <th>Marks Awarded</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="body-data">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>maths
      </td>
      <td id="data">100</td>
      <td id="data1">33</td>
      <td id="data2">54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>english
      </td>
      <td id="data">100</td>
      <td id="data1">33</td>
      <td id="data2">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>science
      </td>
      <td id="data">100</td>
      <td id="data1">33</td>
      <td id="data2">74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-data">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>social science
      </td>
      <td id="data">100</td>
      <td id="data1">33</td>
      <td id="data2">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="total-data">
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">TOTAL </td>
      <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="fulltotal"></td>
      <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="passtotal"></td>
      <td style="border-top: 2px solid #2193b0!important;" id="obtotal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

Result: <strong id='results'></strong>
```

Comment: using this It stopped showing my total values which was showing with my code and also the pass fail is not working. I want it to show fail when one subject is less than required pass marks. Your code is showing same as mine..

Comment: Ok, that should do it. Please check revised answer.

Comment: its working now but its not showing result according to my second condition of the question.

Comment: can we add something in the if else statement which will check the awarded marks<td> values if its less than the required pass <td> marks then also it shows fail.

Comment: ok, so it just needs to find any zero score (marks awarded) - if it does, the result will be 'fail'?

Comment: yeah..not zero but if less than pass marks given there.

Comment: Ok, its updated, and I put it in a testable snippet. Thanks for updating your question with a testable table. i didn't notice that.